# How do I stop MySQL from skipping data during data importing

Tags: mysql, database

I am using the following line of code in MySQL workbench 5.2.47CE to import data.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'E:\data.txt" INTO TABLE mydatabase.mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '  ' ENCLOSED BY '""' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

The problem comes from my data file and the fact that their are multiple lines with the same starting number.

```
data.txt
1     23   1   [0]5930495
1     16   1   [0]4049350
1     45   2   [0]4294283
2     58   1   [0]3298594
2     45   1   [0]3482934
2     34   2   [0]3958493
...
4515  56   1   [0]3945859
4515  21   1   [0]3847382
4515  12   2   [0]4487283
```

The table I get as a result from this is:

```
builid   partid   quantity   barcode
1        23       1          [0]5930495
2        58       1          [0]3298594
...
4515     56       1          [0]3945859
```

The message I get is

```
4515 row(s) affected Records 32769 Deleted:0 Skipped:28254 Warnings:0
```

Why is it skipping values when I import?

Comment: is buildid the primary key of that table?

Comment: does builid have unique constraint?

Comment: Yes, I un-selected that and now it is loading as desired, thank you both.